# How to calculate the difference between 2 dates? javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to calculate the difference between 2 dates: the standard one so 1970-01-01 - 00:00:00
to the current date we are living now in!

I need to know this in hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: What language are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: How are the individual date/time values represented?

Comment: java script, https://gyazo.com/5435555cb1283d9aaf41238ed93b8b7a , this needs to go to hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Note that you should update the question with extra information — and should not link to some other website.  And preferably, you should show your code that isn't working and explain what your problem is, etc.  And you should have included the primary language tag, [tag:javascript], in your question when you asked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to it.

What I did was:

```
var date = new Date(); //date from 1970 when computers started counting.

var hour = date.getHours();
var minute = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

var displayTime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;

document.getElementById("resultaat").innerHTML = displayTime;
```

This fixed everything and now it's showing it correctly. This is also easy to do with days and years.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp